# My Huawei P30 lite doesn't discover other bluetooth devices in my android studio app

Tags: android

I have already searched for the problem that my huawei p30 lite doesn't discover other bluetooth devices. I tried it with an onther device and it worked but I don't get it why it doesn't work on my huawei p30 lite.

Manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.notfallapp">
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/notfallapplogo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">

        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".menubar.MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Login.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Login.SignUpActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".menubar.contact.ContactActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".menubar.contact.AddContactActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".menubar.AlarmsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".menubar.SettingsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".alarm.CallAlarmActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:persistent="true"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".alarm.AlarmCanceledActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".alarm.AlarmSuccesfulActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".menubar.ChangeProfilActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".connectBracelet.AddBraceletActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".menubar.ChangeProfilActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

AddBraceletActivity.kt

```
package com.example.notfallapp.connectBracelet

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Parcelable
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.*
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.example.notfallapp.MainActivity
import com.example.notfallapp.R
import com.example.notfallapp.interfaces.ICreatingOnClickListener

class AddBraceletActivity : Activity(), ICreatingOnClickListener {

    private lateinit var btnSos: Button
    private lateinit var btnHome: ImageButton
    private lateinit var btnContact: ImageButton
    private lateinit var btnAlarms: ImageButton
    private lateinit var btnMap: ImageButton
    private lateinit var btnSettings: ImageButton

    private lateinit var btnRetrySearching: Button
    private lateinit var btnCancel: Button
    private lateinit var tvConnectBracelet: TextView
    private lateinit var lvDevices: ListView
    private lateinit var builder: AlertDialog.Builder
    private var bAdapter: BluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
    private lateinit var mReceiver: BroadcastReceiver
    private var context = this
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_bracelet)

        configureButtons()
        initComponents()

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener() {
            Log.d("ButtonCancel", "Cancel Button was clicked in AddBraceletActivity")
            sureDialog()
            val alert = builder.create()
            alert.show()
        }

        btnRetrySearching.setOnClickListener() {
            Log.d("ButtonSearch", "Search Button was clicked in AddBraceletActivity")
            searchDevices()
        }
        searchDevices()
    }
    private fun configureButtons() {
        // SOS Button
        btnSos = findViewById(R.id.btn_sos)

        // Button bar
        btnHome = findViewById(R.id.btnHome)
        btnAlarms = findViewById(R.id.btnAlarms)
        btnContact = findViewById(R.id.btnContact)
        btnMap = findViewById(R.id.btnMap)
        btnSettings = findViewById(R.id.btnSettings)

        createOnClickListener(this, btnSos, btnHome, btnAlarms, btnContact, btnMap, btnSettings)
    }

    private fun initComponents() {
        btnRetrySearching = findViewById(R.id.btn_retry_searching)
        btnCancel = findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_searching_device)
        tvConnectBracelet = findViewById(R.id.tvConnectBracelet)
        lvDevices = findViewById(R.id.lvDevices)
        builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        mReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                System.out.println("Hello 2")
                val action = intent.action
                if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED == action) {
                    //discovery starts, we can show progress dialog or perform other tasks
                } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED == action) {
                    //discovery finishes, dismis progress dialog
                } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND == action) {
                    //bluetooth device found
                    val device =
                        intent.getParcelableExtra<Parcelable>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE) as BluetoothDevice
                    val toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Found device " + device.name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    toast.show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun searchDevices() {
        //TODO search for Bluetooth devices.
        Log.d("SearchDevices", "SearchDevices was called in AddBraceletActivity")
        if (bAdapter == null) {
            tvConnectBracelet.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.deviceNotSupportBluetooth))
            return;
        }

        if (!bAdapter.isEnabled) {
            val eintent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
            startActivity(eintent)
        }

        val discoverableIntent: Intent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE).apply {
            putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300)
        }
        startActivity(discoverableIntent)

        if (bAdapter.isDiscovering){
            bAdapter.cancelDiscovery()
        }

        /*val pairedDevices = bAdapter.bondedDevices
        if (pairedDevices.size > 0) {
            // There are paired devices. Get the name and address of each paired device.
            for (device in pairedDevices) {
                System.out.println(device.address)
            }
        }*/

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Log.i("info", "No fine location permissions")

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                1)
        }
        bAdapter.startDiscovery()

        val onFoundFilter = IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
        onFoundFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED)
        onFoundFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED)
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, onFoundFilter)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        bAdapter.cancelDiscovery()
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private fun sureDialog() {
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.confirm))
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.sureStopSearching))

        builder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.Yes)) { dialog, which ->
            var intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            dialog.dismiss()
        }

        builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.No)) {dialog, which ->
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

These are my files where I have the permissions and where I scan for bluetooth devices.
Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I solved my problem by reinstall my device to the base settings.